# Is there any program or software that translates English or any other language into Ithkuil?

Tags: list-of-languages, constructed-language

Considering the absurd difficulty of this language, I was wondering if there was a program that could do this. Just for fun, nothing serious.

Comment: Perhaps better asked at [conlang.se].

Comment: Thank you. I tried searching "Artificial Language" in the search tab but it did not appear, so I did not push further. I use StackExchange for other subjects, this is my first time using the Linguistics one, so pardon my ignorance.